# Local variable 'verticalMovementSpeed' might not be initialized before accessing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i made this method in a unity c# script but its giving the error 'Local variable 'verticalMovementSpeed' might not be initialized before accessing'

Code:

```
float VerticalAirMovementSpeed(bool IsGrounded, float verticalMovementInput)
{
    //Makes forward and backward sensitivity (vertical sensitivity) controllable separately form eachother
    float verticalMovementSpeed;
    //forward and backward movement speed in air and on the ground
    if (verticalMovementInput < 0 && !IsGrounded)
    {
        verticalMovementSpeed = backwardAirMovementSpeed;
    }
    else if (verticalMovementInput > 0 && !IsGrounded)
    {
        verticalMovementSpeed = forwardAirMovementSpeed;
    }
    else if (verticalMovementInput > 0 && IsGrounded)
    {
        verticalMovementSpeed = forwardMovementSpeed;
    }
    else if (verticalMovementInput < 0 && IsGrounded)
    {
        verticalMovementSpeed = backwardMovementSpeed;
    }
    
    return verticalMovementSpeed * verticalMovementInput;
}
```

(C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just start with:

```
float verticalMovementSpeed = float.Parse("0.00");
```

That way it would be initialized.

Comment: Thanks, now i get 0 errors but what do i do in that line so i dont make the mistake the next time and so i understand what im doing

Comment: Initializing variables is mostly the right thing to do. So simply do it. A call to float.Parse is to much here. A simple `0f` is sufficient

Comment: oh ok so i should always give a variable a value?

Comment: More or less yes. Not doing it should be an exception. And i don't have a good example at hand were you shouldn't. The compiler typically will tell you if its really needed. For example here you ignored the cases were verticalMovementInput is equal to 0. None of your if cases caught that so the following code (the multiplication) could be reached with an uninitialized value.